# Passing an Abstract Class as an argument in an Method

Tags: c#, abstract

I have recently started learning c# and have come across an issue. I'm not very familiar with the abstract/interface classes yet do understand the basic principles and applications.

I am Currently looking at OOP for c#, I already know the mechanics of OOP, having done it in Java, yet have never used abstract or interface classes there either.

The aim of my code is to pass in an ArrayList of Objects (Both Children of a Common Parent Class) and Print out only those Objects that are of that particular Class. This works, but I was curious to see If I could get the same method to print out all the child Objects of the parent class, If the parent class is abstract.

Parent Class

```
abstract class Person
{
    protected string Name { get; set; }
    protected int Age { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() { return "Person:" + Name + ", " + this.Age; }
}
```

Child Class

```
class Student : Person
{
    private int studID { get; set; }
    private string school { get; set; }
    public Student() { }
    public Student(string name, int age, int studID, string school)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Age = age;
        this.studID = studID;
        this.school = school;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string s = "Student:" + Name + ", " + Age + ", " + studID + ", " + school;
        return s;
    }
}
```

Method Call

```
    private static void StudentDetails(object type)
    {
        ArrayList tmp = new ArrayList();
            //display all
            //foreach (Person p in people) tmp.Add(p);
            foreach (Person p in people)
            {
                if (type.GetType() == p.GetType())
                {
                    tmp.Add(p);
                }
            }
            //etc...
```

Comment: Will you know the type at compile time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't compare GetType() because it doesn't check for inheritence and stuff.
Check the IsAssignableFrom method -> http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx, this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks, This is exactly what I was looking for. Worked perfectly when Implemented with the updated StudentDetails(Type type) Method recommended by nawfal.

Comment: You should always include the relevant code from an offsite link so people can still view it after the content has been removed (which it has been).

Answer (score 1):

If you know the type at compile time you could use:

```
private static void StudentDetails<T>()
{
    ArrayList tmp = new ArrayList();
    foreach (Person p in people)
    {
        if (p is T)
        {
            tmp.Add(p);
        }
    }            
}
```

And call

```
StudentDetails<Student>();
```

Some thoughts:

1. You should change `ArrayList` to something more strongly typed like `List<T>`. In your case `List<Person>`.
2. Give `StudentDetails` a better naming. A method name should be a verb.

Answer (score 1):

If you know the type at compile time, you can do this:

```
var students = people.OfType<Student>().ToList();
```

And completely get rid of the `StudentDetails` method. `OfType<T>` documentation can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913.aspx).

I'm not sure off-hand, but this may also get types that are derived from `T` (in my example, derived from `Student`). The `ToList()` call is only required if you need a `List<T>` as opposed to an `IEnumerable<T>`.

If the `Type` argument is determined at runtime, this solution will ***not*** work as generics require compile-time resolution of types to be coded like this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do *may be* something like :

Do not use `ArrayList`, but use `IEnumerable<Person>` in this case, as all objects are derived from `Person` abstract class.

```
private static void StudentDetails(Type filter)
{
   var filteredTypes = people.Where(p=>p.GetType() == filter);               
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this just fine using your base class (even though it's abstract):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();

        persons.Add(new Student("John", 18, 1, "Stanford"));
        persons.Add(new Student("Matt", 20, 2, "Stanford"));
        persons.Add(new Teacher("Alice", 30));

        StudentDetails(persons);
    }

    private static void StudentDetails(List<Person> people)
    {
        foreach (Person p in people)
        {
            try
            {
                Student s = (Student)p;
                Console.WriteLine(s.ToString());
            }
            catch(InvalidCastException e)
            {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

**First of all:**

The main different between an Interface and an Abstract class is that you can write methods in the base to provide a default behavior for your code. As known that isn't possible in an Interface, because here u only provide the method signatures.

The sample you provided is a bit questionable, for such implementations you really use simple base classes and no abstract classes. To provide a collection or field of your base type you need to use a base which can be instantiated, what is not allowed by the abstract class.

**Now your question:**

Let's think it trough. You want to have a base object which can't be instanced, but you would like to provide a collection of this class... You see the problem. If you really want to do this, there will be a way through many casts and type checking, but with this way the whole idea makes no sense. A better way will be to implement an Interface but with this you aren't able to provide any default behavior!

**My Suggestion:**

For your sample use a normal class Person and let Student Inherit of it. You still got your default ToString method in the base and override it in the Student class.
For future code. Think if you:
need instances of your base (collections, pattern, etc.) -> Simple base or Interface

need default behavior and instances -> Simple base

need instances NO default behavior -> Interface

need default behavior NO instances -> abstract

that’s the things I used to think through when I need to decide how to implement my classes.

hth

Christoph

Comment: Having a collection typed to the abstract base class is not a problem at all, and it doesn't require any casts or type checking.